# GO language always print false condition part in html

Tags: go, go-templates

**About the issue**

I am using Go language and trying to pass bool variable value from function to html. Please check the function `articlesHandler`, in which `IsLoggedIn` value has been initialized to true and it also successfully prints true condition part present in same function.

Now, please check the html block, there are two if conditions, my issue is that it always prints false part instead of true part in html.

Can you suggest something?

**Another issue**

> no such template "anonymous-nav.html"

**main.go code**

```
var templates *template.Template
var pageData pageProps

type pageProps struct {
    IsLoggedIn bool
}

func articlesHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    pageData.IsLoggedIn = true
    templates = template.Must(template.ParseGlob("templates/article/*.html"))
    if pageData.IsLoggedIn == true {
        templates.ParseFiles("templates/authenticated-nav.html")
        fmt.Println("err", "authenticated")
    } else {
        templates.ParseFiles("templates/anonymous-nav.html")
        fmt.Println("err", "anonymous")
    }
    err := templates.ExecuteTemplate(w, "article.html", pageData)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("err", err)
    }
}
func handler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    articlesHandler(w, r)       
}

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", handler)
    pageData = pageProps{
        IsLoggedIn: false,
    }
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
}
```

**Html Code**

```
{{ if .IsLoggedIn }}
    {{ template "authenticated-nav.html" . }}
{{end}}

{{ if not .IsLoggedIn }}
    {{ template "anonymous-nav.html" . }}
{{end}}
```

Answer (score 1):

> my issue is that it always prints false part instead of true part in html

I guess that you said this because you saw this error message:

> html/template:article.html:6:16: no such template "anonymous-nav.html"

But this error message does not mean that `.IsLoggedIn` in `{{ if not .IsLoggedIn }}` is `false`. The `html/template` package calls [escapeTemplate](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/5fe3f0a265c90a9c0346403742c6cafeb154503b/src/html/template/escape.go#L17-L22) to travel all the templates and report an error if any one is not found (no matter whether the template will be rendered or not).

It's easy to observe this behavior with the following demo:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "html/template"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    tmpl, err := template.New("test").Parse(`
{{ if false }}
    {{ template "authenticated-nav.html" . }}
{{end}}`)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    err = tmpl.Execute(os.Stdout, nil)
    fmt.Printf("%v\n", err)
    // Output: html/template:test:3:16: no such template "authenticated-nav.html"
}
```

Please note that the `text/template` package does not have this behavior.

For your use case, I think it's better to write the `article.html` template as:

```html
{{ template "nav" . }}
```

And modify both of `anonymous-nav.html` and `authenticated-nav.html` to define a template with the same name `nav`:

```html
{{define "nav"}}
...
{{end}}
```